# txfonts package is not printed correctly via cups

Tags: pdftex, printing, txfonts

I have a document (not my own) which uses the rtxr font from the txfonts package. When I print this document via cups on my Fedora machine, the font is not rendered. E.g. in offset the 'ff' is not printed. I could create a minimal example which reproduces the error.

The 'ff' is even missing if I use print to file in the print dialog. If I print the file directly on the printer with an USB-stick it also prints fine.

I do not know how to debug the problem or where to start. If this is not the correct place, I am sorry and pleas point out where I might ask the question. Any help is appreciated.

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract offset
\end{abstract}


offset


\end{document}
```

In Fedora 36 using the default PDF Viewer of Gnome and in the print dialog selecting 'Print to File' with the option 'Pdf output',
I get the following:

[image: Missing ff and other errors]

It should look like:

[image]

System: Fedora 36 6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64

Cups: 2.4.2

pdflatex: 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)

Comment: possibly not related but `txfonts` has been deprecated for some years, what do you get with `\usepackage{newtxtext}\usepackage{newtxmath}` ?

Comment: With these packages, everything works fine. The problem is, that it is not my own file, so I can not change it. I recognized such errors in some of my last printouts, so I would like to tackle it.

Comment: what answer do you want? if bugs on the fonts were fixed with new fonts 10 years ago but you have to use the old ones, you have to accept the bugs. do you only have pdf? in which case you may be able to do something, but not really a tex question

Comment: Since, the file prints fine if printed directly on the printer I doubt, that the problem is really in the txfonts package. I think it is located somewhere in the cups tool chain. So I thought, in this stack exchange people might know about such problems.

Comment: Maybe it would work to convert all fonts to curves/outlines before printing? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797418/replace-all-font-glyphs-in-a-pdf-by-converting-them-to-outline-shapes for example.

Comment: It might be useful if you specify **exactly** how you print, is this from a PDF viewer?

Comment: Thanks for the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797418/replace-all-font-glyphs-in-a-pdf-by-converting-them-to-outline-shapes tip. This is a backup, I can use in the future.

Comment: I updated the question and added the description on how I print: In Fedora 36 using the default PDF Viewer of Gnome and in the print dialog selecting 'Print to File' with the option 'Pdf output', I get the following:

Comment: Which exact program is that PDF viewer of Gnome? Just normal Evince? I had no issues printing the PDF from Evince on my older Linux box.

Comment: The default is evience. If you have no issue, this might indicate that the pipeline has changed and a new tool has some problems. Which system are you running, what is you cups version?

Comment: I can't reproduce with CUPS 2.4.1 (pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22) on Ubuntu using Evince, there the 'printed' pdf looks fine. Maybe there is a local issue with your CUPS configuration, or you have some other version of `rtxr` installed without the `ff` ligature and something in the toolchain is using that other version? That would be difficult to troubleshoot, maybe you can print to pdf using CUPS from the terminal to get more verbose output on which font files are actually used.

Comment: I tried to use lp but with no luck. A lpstat -p does not give me the file printer. I also could not add a printer with destination file:/temp.pdf (Error: File device URIs have been disabled.) Do you have a reference where printing with cups to a file from a command line is explained?